# Deconstructing/Hacking NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, operating-system

I am trying to understand Node internal workings and am at a point where I am not able to piece together how Node, which is written in js, hooks/binds into the low level system calls written in C/C++.

When I write this piece of code -

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) { res.end('Hacking Node'); });
server.listen(8081);
```

How does server.listen listen the specific port for which only the OS has access to? Same goes with various other features.

The journey so far has been this.

I checked the [net.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js) and os.js files. But could not make out much.

Also I dug into process file written in C - both unix and [windows](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/win/process.c) versions.

Finally,after further investigation hit the Node.js file

```
// https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/6cbfcdad46d733bb04332063727e304e449dc86b/src/node.js
```

which had the following comment -

```
// This file is invoked by node::Load in src/node.cc, and responsible for
// bootstrapping the node.js core. Special caution is given to the performance
// of the startup process, so many dependencies are invoked lazily.
```

And Node.cc loads this Node.js file in line 2708.

```
// https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/6cbfcdad46d733bb04332063727e304e449dc86b/src/node.cc - line 2708
```

That is as far as I got. Can someone point me what happens next and help me fill in the pieces of this puzzle.

Comment: So, just to be clear, what you're asking is: _"How exactly does NodeJS work?"_, right?

Comment: Cerbrus, ya. But with more lower level details esp the js/OS interface.

Comment: By calling the OS libraries like any other language would do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was surprised no one mentioned about libuv. Here is a schematic. (It's not 100% accurate).

```
              2 V8 compiler
             /             \
            /               \
   1 Your code              3 node.js core system libraries(net,fs,events)
                                       JavaScript
                                      ------------    
                                     V8 bindings(C++)
                                         / | \
                                        /  |  \
                              4 node.js platform code C/C++
                                  events   fs  net
                                        \  |  /
                                         \ | / 
                                          \|/
                                        runs on
                                     5 libuv C/C++
                               High Performance Event Loop
                                           |
                                        syscalls
                                           |
                                        6 Kernel
```

Remember how you can do .toString() and show JS functions. That does not work for V8 bindings (shows [native code]). node.js platform (C++) functions have V8 bindings. Because node gives evented and async execution, everything you do on event loop runs on libuv. An old [blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/09/23/libuv-status-report/) showing libuv usage.

libuv handles the scheduling of system calls for you and V8 handles your JS code. node extends JS to system.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you user568109. Really that helped me to get a whole picture that its no single thing but a combo of  js, V8, libuv, kernel.  It also enabled me to dive little deeper till a point of known abstraction.

I wanted to share some knowledge I gathered along the way. (If its too trivial,please forgive my ignorence)

1. First thing, as a person who used js on the browser sitting on top of the DOM APIs already implemented on the browser, it did not occur to me that one could create a fresh API on top of V8. user568109's bit on the [native code] led me [here](http://syskall.com/how-to-roll-out-your-own-javascript-api-with/) and [here](http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/). Node bindings was the most important piece of this puzzle.

Though to the plain eyes the following js codelines may appear as js, actually they are different. One is a pure js->js call while the second one is realized by the underlying binding.

```
//normal js
var x = require('http');
var s = x.createServer();

//native binding
var tty = process.binding('tty_wrap');
tty.guessHandleType();
```

1. With the bindings' native implementation in C++, the surface javascript is nothing but a syntactic sugar or an abstraction of the underlying C++ pieces. This [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5Xq3XblDRI) by Nikhil Marathe - slides [here](http://www.slideshare.net/nsm.nikhil/writing-native-bindings-to-nodejs-in-c) -  helped to understand things better.
2. Now that the js and V8 glue had been unravelled, it was clear that once we are in the C/C++ level, it could then speak to other native kernel libraries either directly(if needed) or through libuv. This [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGn60vDSxQ4) by Bert Belder knid of helped understand libuv in more detail.

Having understood this picture, now I can understand what happens when I see the following lines.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) { res.end('Hacking Node'); });
server.listen(8081);
```